# IPython notebook 3.0 automatically close brackets

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've just downloaded the new IPython 3.0 version.

Some behaviour in the notebook has changed. Before, when I typed a open bracket it automatically closed it. This was particularly useful when selecting a text and putting brackets around it with just one click.

I tried to adjust ~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js

where I added

```
    if (IPython.CodeCell) {
      IPython.CodeCell.options_default.cm_config.autoCloseBrackets = true;
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to do the job.

How can I get the old behaviour back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug fix is in progress and will be release probably in 3.1 see [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7919)

Answer (score 3):

from https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7896

"
in /IPython/html/static/notebook/js/codecell.js around line 120 smth, near mode: 'ipython', in cm_config add the key autoCloseBrackets: true The exact name/casing of option is somewhere in codemirror manual."

This worked for me. In line 130 I added:

```
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
```

now it auto closes brackets.

Comment: I'm on the developers version now, and unfortunately this doesn't work for me.